# In what way String Deduplication is different from String interning

Tags: java, string, g1gc

As we know In Java String, process of storing and maintaining only one literal of any String is String interning.
I felt String  Deduplication serves the same purpose when I read it first time.

could some one explain Deduplication advantage over String intern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interning happens only for constant strings and strings that you manually intern.

String deduplication happens automatically in the background for all strings, including ones you create at runtime.